# How can I remove linux from a laptop

Tags: uninstall

Recently, I installed linux on my dad's computer, but now he wants it removed.  How can I remove it, and get Windows XP back? or at least set Windows XP as default boot OS?

I need this as soon as possible.

Comment: You can refer this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller , To mods,  similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into Windows and install EasyBCD on it.

Open it.

In the Deployment section, you'll have an option to write the Windows XP bootloader in the MBR. Click on it and reboot.

If everything goes well, and Windows boots up without encountering GRUB, delete the Linux partition.

Comment: didin't work, are you sure thats the write button?

Comment: Pretty sure. Anyway, here's another way. Boot into live from a linux live CD and execute this command **grub-install /dev/sda** and then **update-grub**. This will definitely work but the dafault bootloader will be replaced by GRUB (the default Linux bootloader).

Comment: PS - Formatting the linux partition should be your first step _(before executing these commands)_.

Comment: didnt work, but i want this question closed
LOL i just removed the linux entry in grub so it seems like i deleted it :) thanks tho